# Use Qt Pyside2 with asyncio await syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, python-asyncio

How to await this function ([src](https://gist.github.com/Bomberus/0000ef0d56ee0aac285d9e2045452b0b) ) in the main loop of pyside2:

```
async def do_request(value): #asyncqt maybe possible
    #print("do request")
    await asyncio.sleep(value)
    #print("request finished")
    return value

async def eventFilter(self, source, event): #impossible, needs pyside2 rewrite
     ...
```

I am very reluctant to use any nonoffical stuff, so pyside2: i looked into examples of pyside2 having Qthreads examples, but no asyncio await. My lib uses asyncio so how to await in pyside2?

This is a serious issue: The https://github.com/harvimt/quamash/issues/104 does not support pyside2 and https://github.com/gmarull/asyncqt   is not maintained. What is the solution?
Please how to integrate such simple call. i fear breaks/bugs on nonmaintained repos

Comment: I didn't vote either way, but you can always see the reason if you mouse over the downvote arrow. No one is obliged to give any further explanation than that.

Comment: I agree, this is some serious issue, and not an easy one to fix... takes someone with knowledge how to interoperate between different event loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ol5IuJyw-Tg using built in `qthread qrunnable qthread` to not block main gui thread is way to go.

for examples see https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/examples/corelib and browse the source (its for pyside2)

Answer (score 0):

There are external libraries (asyncqt, qasync) to make `Qt` and `asyncio` play nicely, but such libraries seem to have poor support. The official PySide6 seems to have proper support with a module called `QtAsyncio` which is probably best ([example here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_async_minimal.html)).

BUT this was affecting me in PySide2, and I found it best to simply run my `asyncio` event loop in a separate `threading.Thread`, with the Qt `exec_` event loop in the main thread, and communicating between them with Qt Slots/Signals. That way could I fetch things in the background with the async/await syntax and keep the window running smoothly.

```py
import threading
import asyncio
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

async def foo():
    for i in range(10):
        label.setText(str(i))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

app = QApplication()
label = QLabel()
label.show()
threading.Thread(target=lambda: asyncio.run(foo()), daemon=True).start()
app.exec_()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

PyQt is very popular. Though some may not want it because of licensing issues. Whether you choose PyQt or PySide, [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) has some very nice functionality. In particular, you can use the `singleShot()` method to run code at a specific delay.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QTimer

def myfunc():
    # do your stuff here
    pass

def do_request(self, value):
    # call static function singleShot
    QTimer.singleShot( delay_msec, myfunc)
```

you can also `start()` a QTimer to run a task at a regular `interval`.

Comment: would downvote: not realted to the async await lib and pyside2 is way to go since official.

Comment: you're right. there's no asyncio here. i was throwing out QTimer as it has some nice features that you might be able to use instead.